# Dictionary Comprehensions - don't generate key/value pairs with empty list value

Tags: python

The following code

```
k = 7
{ i: [j for j in range(10) if abs(i-j)==k] for i in range(10) }
```

generates the following value

```
{0: [7], 1: [8], 2: [9], 3: [], 4: [], 5: [], 6: [], 7: [0], 8: [1], 9: [2]}
```

There are values with empty list. How to generate the dictionary items with only non-empty value?

```
{0: [7], 1: [8], 2: [9], 7: [0], 8: [1], 9: [2]}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [Assignment Expression (PEP 572)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) in Python 3.8+ which is notably designed for this kind of cases (it avoids the 2 steps or the 2 for-loop mentionned in the other answers):

```
k = 7
{ i: t for i in range(10) if (t:= [j for j in range(10) if abs(i-j)==k]) }
```

Answer (score 4):

Playing devil's advocate a bit here, but any one-liner solution is going to be lengthy to the point of being difficult to maintain. Dictionary comprehensions etc are not the be-all-and-end-all, and you might find that an explicit loop is easier to deal with (although still using the inner list comprehension).

```
k = 7
result = {}
for i in range(10):
    v = [j for j in range(10) if abs(i-j)==k]
    if v:
        result[i] = v

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid cmoputing twice the list, once to check if empty and one to retrieve it, I'd suggest you first build the dict with the list as value, then iterate just to check is the list is not empty

```
res = {k:v for k,v in { i: [j for j in range(10) if abs(i-j)==k] for i in range(10) }.items() if v}
```

To help you can see it in 2 steps

```
res = { i: [j for j in range(10) if abs(i-j)==k] for i in range(10) }
res = {k:v for k,v in res.items() if v}
```

---

Then problem in one step is that the list will be computed twice

```
res = { i: [j for j in range(10) if abs(i-j)==k] 
         for i in range(10) 
         if [j for j in range(10) if abs(i-j)==k]}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could filter afterwards with an outer dictionary comprehension, or you could iterate on another tuple made of the generated list as sole item and filter on it:

```
k = 7
res = { i: lst for i in range(10) for lst in ([j for j in range(10) if abs(i-j)==k],) if lst}
```

(using a tuple is slightly less memory greedy for this specific use)